# No Title and no description using embed button

Tags: flattr

Isn't Flattr able to retrieve the page title and description?
I used the embed button (https://flattr.com/embed) but when I click on the link, I get a Flattr thing with no title and no description (and I can't edit it).

Right now I filled up all the fields (see http://mesamatrix.net/ at the bottom of the page). But I don't know if that's the right way of doing it.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Make it look like this:

```
&button=compact&title='+encodeURIComponent('YOUR TITLE HERE')+'&url='+encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
```